# How can I access a field in a jqgrid modal edit dialog on jquery ajax method?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid that is working great for displaying, paging, sorting, adding, editing data. I need to add custom validation on a particular field in the add/edit modal dialog before submitting. I have implemented the beforeCheckValues event for that and it works fine, however I am not sure how to grab a value from the edit dialog - how can I do that? I was looking into "getRowData", but I dont believe that will drill down into what is in the modal edit dialog. My add/edit dialog has more fields that the regular grid, everything is pulled back at once, it's just hidden until edit time.

jqgrid definition snippet:

```
        {
            name: 'SecurityControlNumber', jsonmap: 'SecurityControlNumber', index: 'SecurityControlNumber', width: 150, editable: true, hidden: true,
            editrules:
                {
                    edithidden: true, required: true
                },
            formoptions:
                {
                    elmsuffix: ' *'
                },
            hidedlg: true
        },
```

beforeCheckValues event:

```
  beforeCheckValues: function (postdata, formid, mode) {
                var options = {
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    url: "@Url.Action("CheckSecurityControlNumber")",
                    data: { securityControlNumber: $('#gridDetail').jqgrid('getRowData') }, // <-- need to get field in modal here
                    dataType: 'json',
                    context: $(this),
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data.returnvalue);
                        alert('made it to ajax call');

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Something happened...  Error is.. : ' + errorThrown);
                    },
                };

                $.ajax(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly below is what you want(If data is in the popup)

```
 data: { securityControlNumber: $('input#SecurityControlNumber').val() },//for text input

 data: { securityControlNumber: $('select#SecurityControlNumber option:selected').val() },//for dropdown
```

Comment: Where should I write beforeCheckValues  event in my ASP.NET MVC application?